# How to add metadata to WOFF file?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I need to add a metadata.xml to a WOFF file that I have created using font-squirrel in order to use it with @font-face.

I want to add a metadata.xml to WOFF file like this one (that explains all about it):

http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-a

I was told I can do it with this sfnt2woff but it is **NOT USER FRIENDLY and quite complicated**. I was wondering if there are other ways to do it (font-squirrel? other font convertors?)

thanks,
Alon

Comment: Came here to find a solution for viewing the metadata of a woff-file: [fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure why you would need to add the metadata to the font, it works perfectly well without the metadata.xml

The xml file only adds information for font designers or vendors to include licensing or other information.

Top of css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: font_name";
src: url('fonts/font_name.eot');
src: url('fonts/font_name.woff') format('woff'),  url('fonts/font_name.ttf') format('truetype'),  url('fonts/font_name.svg') format('svg');
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

And then for example:

```
body {
font-family: "droid sans", Verdana;
}
```

Edit1:

Create somewhere a folder called myfonts
place in that folder your *metadata.xml* the *font.ttf*(source font) and the *sfnt2woff.exe* (located here: http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/sfnt2woff.exe)

Create a text file open it, place this inside it

```
sfnt2woff -v 1.0 -m metadata.xml droid_sans.ttf
```

save it to that folder and call it: do-it-now.bat

Go to the folder and click once you are done.
A font.woff should appear with metadata.xml added to it.

Usage for sfnt2woff:

```
sfnt2woff [-v <maj>.<min>] [-m <metadata.xml>] [-p <private.dat>] <otffile>
package OpenType <otffile> as WOFF, creating <otffile>.woff
Options:
-v <maj>.<min>     set font version number (major and minor, both integers)
-m <metadata.xml>  include metadata from <metadata.xml> (not validated)
-p <private.dat>   include private data block
```

Comment: I need to add this metadata because the designer of the font asked me to put this data there...

Comment: thank you very much! worked like charm :) thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

I too have a WOFF font. I tried both the following commands:

1. `sfnt2woff -v 1.0 -m metadata.xml <fontfile>.ttf`
2. `sfnt2woff  samagana.ttf`

The font is 1k larger than the first one. However, Firefox → Tools → Page Info → Fonts
does not display the included meta data. Maybe it is a bug in the Font Information extension, or this program.